# Display Passport Error Message directly to HTML page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I am currently trying to display an error message to my HTML page whenever a user fails a login. I am not using flash, or any template engine to render the message.

What I am trying exactly to do is to send a message whenever the **POST** form fails to log a user and try to catch it with my Angular Front End. The main problem that I am facing is actually sending a correct message.

Here is my NodeJS Backend:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
        console.log('here is Authenticated', req.isAuthenticated())
        if (req.isAuthenticated()){
            return next();
        }else{
            res.status(401).json({"message": "You are not authorized to access this page. Please log in."});
            console.log("routes Print log You Cannot Log in!");   
        }
    }
```

Here is my POST Form:

```
 app.post('/login',
        passport.authenticate('local', {failWithError: true }),
        function(req, res) {
            res.redirect('/index');
        });
```

I am not sure how to set a message to be send on the HTML page, since when I use: `res.status(401).json({"message": "You are not authorized to access this page. Please log in."});` instead of `{failWithError: true }`

On my Client side, I am using AngularJS and I'm trying to catch the message like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("/login").then(function(res){
      // Do stuff if login is successful
         })
         .catch(function(res) {
           $scope.message = res.data.message;
          })
      });
```

How can I send a failed login message from my Node Backend without using **Flash** or any **template engine**? Am I catching the message correctly???

Comment: try instead of `res.json` --> `throw new Error("You are not authorized to access this page. Please log in.")`

Comment: @SuperVeetz yes I know what I have to do, I don't know how to do it. Plus I need to change the message inside the **post form** -> `passport.authenticate('local', {failWithError: true})`

Comment: Can't you use a custom callback for `passport.authenticate()` instead of a config object?

Comment: @MikaelLennholm I am quite new to MEAN stack and specifically Passport. I'm currently using passport `passport.authenticate()` but I'm not sure how to use a custom callback.

Comment: I've never used passport myself but the documentation about custom callback seems pretty straight-forward to me. http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate

Comment: yes it is, if you are using FlashMessage to display the error + template engine...which I am not. That's why I am having difficulties.